# How to call a function from `setInterval`?

Tags: javascript

```
function Obj() {
    this.func1 = function() {
            this.func2();
        },
        this.func2 = function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                this.func2();
            }, 200);
        }
}

function main() {
    var obj = new Obj();
    obj.func1();
}
main();
```

I have the following exception:

```
this.func2(); ^ TypeError: this.func2 is not a function

at Timeout._onTimeout(C: \Users\ Admin\ Desktop\ CANVAS\ test.js: 15: 12)
at ontimeout(timers.js: 365: 14)
at tryOnTimeout(timers.js: 237: 5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout(timers.js: 207: 5)
```

Why `this.func2` is function when I call without `setInterval` and is not a function when I call from `setInterval`?

Comment: Because `this` (which refers to the object) is lost when called from a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Cause this is not referring to Obj in your case. That context has been changed and this is referring to setInterval context.

NOte the line `var self = this;`, which storing `this` for later usage.

This should work

```
function Obj() {



  this.func1 = function() {
    this.func2();

  },

  this.func2 = function() {

    setInterval(function(){
      self.func2();
    }, 200);

  }

}

function main() {
  var obj = new Obj();
  obj.func1();

}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
function Obj() {

  this.func1 = function() {
    this.func2();

  },

  this.func2 = function() {

    setInterval(function(){
      this.func2();
    }.bind(this), 200);

  }

}
```

But this will soon lead to an overflow, because you create a new interval on each execution. Maybe you wanted to use `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

You can **bind** `this`

```
this.func2 = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    this.func2();
  }.bind(this), 200);

}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x7bsxy1L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the context inside of `setTimeout` is the top-level, not the context of your object, so `this` will point to `window` (in a browser) instead of your object. There are a couple of ways to solve the problem.

The most recent version is to use the `bind` method to bind the context of your function.

```js
function Obj() {
  this.func1 = function() {
    this.func2();
  },

  this.func2 = function() {
    console.log('hi');
    setTimeout(this.func2.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}

function main() {
  var obj = new Obj();
  obj.func1();
}

main();
```

Notice that I use `this.func2.bind(this)` as the callback for `setTimeout` (same for `setInterval`, just your example would be quite spammy if I left it with that). That means that no matter where it's called, it's `this` will always be your object.

The slightly older way to do it is to wrap it up in self-calling function that'll isolate it to a scope that has `this` set to your object.

```js
function Obj() {
  this.func1 = function() {
    this.func2();
  },

  this.func2 = function() {
    console.log('hi');
    setTimeout((function(self){
      return function () {
        self.func2();
      }
    })(this), 1000);
  }
}

function main() {
  var obj = new Obj();
  obj.func1();
}

main();
```

This way is a bit more involved, but basically I just wrapped what you originally had in a self-calling function that passes in `this` as a parameter for `self`, then I use `self.func2()` inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not passed to your `setInterval` callback because it is always called in the global context, just like when you use `setTimeout`.

`this` is either `undefined` (in `'use strict'` mode) or the `window` object (in regular/loose mode). You *can* pass extra arguments to `setInterval`, though, and these are passed on to your callback:

```js
this.func2 = function() {
  setInterval(function(self) {
    self.func2()
  }, 200, this)
}
```

### Demo Snippet

```js
function Obj() {

  this.func1 = function() {
    this.func2()
  }

  this.func2 = function() {
    setInterval(function(self) {
      console.log(typeof self.func2) //=> 'function'
    }, 200, this)
  }

}

function main() {
  var obj = new Obj()
  obj.func1()
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function:

```js
        this.func2 = function() {
            setInterval(() => {   this.func2();    }, 200);
        }
```